# Open Graph on LinkedIn does not work for my client's site

Tags: linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph

For some reason sharing links on LinkedIn from my client's site does not work.
I've checked the specifications on https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en and it looks like all the og meta tags re correct. Sharing on other social media works without problems. It's only on LinkedIn where the Open Graph data is not picked up.

Here is a sample URL which does not work on LinkedIn:
https://nomadandvillager.com/bestemmingen/kenia/mbara/vrouwenbesnijdenis/

Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to share a bit more on how you're getting the tags to render on Facebook and the like?

I encountered the same problem (My site runs on Angular), but my approach was to redirect the LinkedInBot via .htaccess.

Eventually, I gave up, and wrote a custom share button with [LinkedIn's rest API](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin)

With it, you will be able to specify the details of the share, and avoid the messy workarounds for LinkedIn.

**Direct Sharing on LinkedIn**

[image]

**Sharing via REST API**

[image]

Original link: http://blog.crazy.technology/post/Clash-of-Clans---How-to-use-the-Web-API-570dd2b2

Comment: Hi Edwin. I understand that using the REST API I can pass the exact parameters but for this client it's important that direct sharing on LinkedIn works well.
Here is another example of a URL: https://nomadandvillager.com/bestemmingen/wereld/algemeen-wereld/de-meest-vrouwonvriendelijke-landen/

Comment: @MarcSelman Hi Marc, I think I've stumbled upon the right way to do it. Please take a look at my updated answer. :) The link sharing works for my site now.

Comment: Apparently i succeeded because I switched from Angular to Angular Universal. Removed the answer.

Comment: @EdwinChua Even I am using SSR but still meta image is not being captured by LinkedIn , any Luck?